# How to pass more then 100 arguments into postgresSQL function

Tags: postgresql

[When passing more then 100 arguments into postgresql function getting error]

ERROR:  cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function

Comment: Use an array as a single parameter

Comment: Thank you for your reply -#But in my  select query   passing different  data types  as arguments into postgressql function , as per my knowledge array should  take  only any single data type

Comment: How about passing JSON in?

Comment: Why do you want to pass 100+ parameters to *anything*? IIRC Checkstyle limits parameters to 5. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You may get better advice if you explain what the function does and what the parameters mean. As already pointed out, a function with hundreds of parameters feels clunky and hard to maintain and perhaps there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a query to your function or rather query parameters and run the query inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
RETURN $1
$$, '[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]')
$$) AS (res agtype);
By passing the list as a single-string argument, you are able to bypass this limitation since the entire list is treated as a single argument. The cypher function can then reference the list using a positional placeholder like $1. this is a way around to overcome the limitations of an argument as it makes no scene to pass all the arguments and yet they are not stored in a list